# Iterate a MatchCollection backwards

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

How can I iterate backwards a regexp's MatchCollection?
The following code doesn't work (VBA-MSWORD)

`Set mtch = foundmatches(m)` gives 'Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)'

```
Dim regex As New regexp
Dim foundmatches As MatchCollection
Dim mtch As Match

With regex
    .PATTERN = "somepattern"
    .Global = True
    Set foundmatches = .Execute(ActiveDocument.Range)
End With

For m = foundmatches.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set mtch = foundmatches(m) 'Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)
    'do stuff
Next m
```

Thanks

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a great description of what happens when you run that

Comment: Matches is zero-based, so first item is at position 0 and last is at `foundmatches.Count - 1`

Comment: One wonders why you're not using Word's built-in wildcard Find tools, which can do their own direction-based processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, as the Matches collection is zero-based

```
For m = foundmatches.Count -1 To 0 Step -1
    Set mtch = foundmatches(m) 'Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)
    'do stuff
Next m
```